# table not adding to database

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

I am currently creating my site and have come to a point where I am to add content to my database

my add.php code is this:

```
  <?php

session_start();

include_once('../include/connection.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
      if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['content'])) {
             $title = $_POST['title'];
             $content = nl2br($_POST['content']);
             $image = $_POST['Image URL'];
             $link = $_POST['Link'];
             $price = $_POST['Price'];

if (empty($title) or empty($content)) {
             $error = 'All Fields Are Required!';
}else{
  $query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO apps (app_title, app_content, app_img, app_link, app_price) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
     $query->bindValue(1, $title);
     $query->bindValue(2, $content);
     $query->bindValue(3, $image);
     $query->bindValue(4, $link);
     $query->bindValue(5, $price);

     $query->execute();
    header('location: index.php');
}

}
          ?>

<html>
<head>
<title>testing</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<a href="index.php" id="logo">CMS</a>

<br />


<h4>Add Article</h4>

<?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
     <small style="color:#aa0000;"><?php echo $error; ?></small><br /><br />
<?php } ?>

<form action="add.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">

<input type="text" value="" name="title" placeholder="Title" /><br /><br />
<textarea rows="15" cols="50" value="" placeholder="Content" name="content"></textarea><br /><br />
<input type="text" value="" name="Image URL" placeholder="Image URL" /><br /><br />
<input type="text" value="" name="Link" placeholder="Link" /><br /><br />
<input type="text" value="" name="Price" placeholder="Price" /><br /><br />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Article" />

</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>


<?php
}else{
       header('location: index.php');
}

?>
```

it loads ok and works file on the display but it does not add the info to my database called apps.

please can someone tell me why?

thank you.

Comment: Where do you create `$pdo`?  Do you have error reporting turned on for it?

Comment: hi. the only error log i have is on cpanel which is created when the page does not load. As the page loads there is nothing to display in this error log. is there another way to get all errors?

Comment: the file above is called add.php yes as explained above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually your variables looks wrong.

try this

```
         $image = $_POST['Image URL'];
         $link = $_POST['Link'];
         $price = $_POST['Price'];
```

EDIT.   you should add `value="something"` to your inputs

```
   <input type="text" value="" name="title" placeholder="Title" /><br /><br />
   <textarea rows="15" cols="50" value="" placeholder="Content" name="content"></textarea><br /><br />
```

EDIT:2

give a name to the submit button

```
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Article" />
```

Comment: just keep getting this error message when ading the last bit of code. PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE

Comment: i added it here: $query->execute();
    header('location: index.php');
}

}else{echo "somthing goes wrong" ; } and it just displays it at the top of my page http://www.xclo.co.uk/mobile/appdonate/admin/add.php

Comment: Yes. that is where it is at the moment and it justs displays the echo note at the top of my page

Comment: ok. done. however the else note that you added is still displayed

Comment: thats why they are empty and not set.

Comment: done. but all that does is adds the text that I add inside the "" into my text field. this does not add to the database.

Comment: Still no joy I'm afraid. My now full code is now in the original post.

Comment: i dont know why i doesnt work , but it something with your html form , . try add a name to form `<form name = "myform" action="add.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">`

Answer (score 0):

ECHO_ME-

This code works:

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once('../include/connection.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
      if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['content'])) {
             $title = $_POST['title'];
             $content = nl2br($_POST['content']);

if (empty($title) or empty($content)) {
             $error = 'All Fields Are Required!';
}else{
     $query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO apps (app_title, app_content, app_timestamp) VALUES(?, ?, ?)');
     $query->bindValue(1, $title);
     $query->bindValue(2, $content);
     $query->bindValue(3, time());

     $query->execute();
    header('location: index.php');
}

}
          ?>

<html>
<head>
<title>testing</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<a href="index.php" id="logo">CMS</a>

<br />


<h4>Add Article</h4>

<?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
     <small style="color:#aa0000;"><?php echo $error; ?></small><br /><br />
<?php } ?>

<form action="add.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">

<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" /><br /><br />
<textarea rows="15" cols="50" placeholder="Content" name="content"></textarea><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Add Article" />

</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>


<?php
}else{
       header('location: index.php');
}

?>
```

But it's when I go to add new fields that causes the problem. All the past little things that you have requested will make no difference to the current code I do not think.

Any more suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Also: I added $query->execute();
exit();
header('location: index.php'); 
After the query and tried to enter filled in the form then hit submit and it displayed a blank white screen. Which tells me that the error is the query.